# Re- proportion pandas column with new adjustments to add up to 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

My current column contains proportions like this :

```
Name   |  Prop |

US     |  0.25 | 
UK     |  0.30 | 
AUS    |  0.45 |
```

A new row has been added with its proportion ;

```
Name   |  Prop |

US     |  0.25 | 
UK     |  0.30 | 
AUS    |  0.45 |
DEN    |  0.10 |
```

Calculate new proportions of the column after adding a new row, so that **the other rows are adjusted, keeping new row's proportion constant and the sum of the proportions is 1**

```
Name   |  Prop |

US     |  x | 
UK     |  x | 
AUS    |  x |
DEN    |  0.10 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['Prop'] = df['Prop'].div(df['Prop'].sum())
print(df)

  Name      Prop
0   US  0.227273
1   UK  0.272727
2  AUS  0.409091
3  DEN  0.090909

#df['Prop'].sum() #checking now
#1.0
```

**EDIT**

```
vals_to_scale = df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'Prop']
df.loc[df.index[:-1], 'Prop'] = (vals_to_scale.div(vals_to_scale.sum())
                                              .mul(1-df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Prop']))
print(df)
Name   Prop
0   US  0.225
1   UK  0.270
2  AUS  0.405
3  DEN  0.100
```

Here we are indexing data with [`DataFrame.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: I divide each term in the series by the sum of the terms in the series

Comment: in other words the values ​​are being scaled so that the sum is 1 linearly. 
I assumed you wanted linear scaling

Comment: Thanks, can you help answer the same question with the new modification(edited the question)